# sql server complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

[image: SQL SERVER]

1st one is the source table and 2nd one is the destination table, so in 2nd table by using unpivot the the 12 month columns converted into single column and YTD field should be update automatically. If the month name is Jan means the YTD field will Jan data only, if it is Feb means it will add the Jan data with Feb data. same if it is Dec means it will add from Jan to Dec of the same row.

Comment: Instead of Image it is better to provide as text of these input data

Comment: What you have tried and whats your issue?

Comment: sorry... i can't think any logic for this type of requirement. that's why i posted it in staskoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cross apply(values ...)` to unpivot your data:

```
select 
    t.[oru code]
  , t.[bg name]
  , t.[bu name]
  , t.[domain]
  , t.KPI
  , t.UoM
  , t.[Year]
  , t.[ACT/TARGET]
  , v.[Month]
  , v.KPI
  , t.[YTD/ITM]
from t
  cross apply (values 
    ('Jan',Jan) ,('Feb',Feb) ,('Mar',Mar)
   ,('April',April) ,('May',May) ,('Jun',Jun)
   ,('Jul',Jul) ,('Aug',Aug) ,('Sep',Sep)
   ,('Oct',Oct) ,('Nov',Nov) ,('Dec',Dec)
    ) v ([Month],KPI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select all your Month indivitually and then UNION them:

```
select [ORU code], [BG Name], YEAR, 'Jan' as [Month], [Jan] as [KPI #], [Jan] 
as [YTD/ITM] from  source_table 
union all
select [ORU code], [BG Name], YEAR, 'Feb' as [Month], [Feb] as [KPI #], [Jan]+
[Feb]  as [YTD/ITM] from  source_table 
union all
select ....
```

you get the Idea

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you require is to do unpivot as below:

```
Select *, [YTD] = sum(yourYTD calculation column) over(partition by [OruCode],[year] order by Month) from (
   Select OruCode, BGName ---your required columns upto dec
       from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2
 )
 unpivot (KPINo for [Month] in ([Jan],[Feb]...) ) p
```

Comment: after Unpivot i need to update the YTD field based on month values. means cumulative sum.

Comment: i mean if the month name is jan than it will update the jan month value in the YTD column, if it is feb than the YTD column will be update Jan value + feb value, same as if it is May than YTD=jan+feb+mar+apr+may

Comment: yep that is what my query will do